# I am trying to pull a value from oracle based on button value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I am using a bootstrap modal to pop up when a row is clicked in a table. When it pops up I am getting all the values I need. I have three buttons in the modal. I need one of them to only show based on one of the values that are showing. I currently have a php if statement to determine whether or not the button will show. I am not sure how to get the value from the current modal into the php if statement

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Message Information</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div id="rowID" class="modal-body">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <!-- bgcolor="#D4AF37" -->
                    <tr>
                        <th>Note Code</th>
                        <th>Start Date</th>
                        <th>End Date</th>
                        <th>Recurring</th>
                        <th>Active</th>
                        <th>Activity Date</th>
                        <th>Message Key</th>
                        <th>Period Key</th>
                        <!--                <th>Message Text</th> -->
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="noteCode"></td>
                        <td id="startDate"></td>
                        <td id="endDate"></td>
                        <td id="recurring"</td>
                        <td id="active"></td>
                        <td id="activityDate"></td>
                        <td id="messageKey"></td>
                        <td id="periodKey"></td>
                        <!--                   <td id="messageText"</td> -->
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <h5>
                <b>Message text</b>
            </h5>
            <p style="font-size: 16px" id="messageText"</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <div id="end" class="text-left">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-end" title="Stop Message Period">Stop</button>
            <?php
            $can_delete = $bw_message->can_delete($$period_key);
            if ($can_delete) {
                echo '<div id="delete" class="text-left">';
                echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-delete" title="Delete Message Period">Delete</button>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
            ?>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

The specific statement I am using is this

```
<?php
            $can_delete = $bw_message->can_delete($$period_key);
            if ($can_delete) {
                echo '<div id="delete" class="text-left">';
                echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-delete" title="Delete Message Period">Delete</button>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
            ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot use PHP like this. You'd have to make a separate AJAX call to your php using JavaSctript and decide based on result. Skip the PHP and just do it in javascript. After you open Modal... you know the values. Use the values to .show() or .hide() the button.

Comment: Why don't you try in Javascript?

Comment: I will try that. I am relatively new to javascript was not sure how to do that.